# Prestashop 1.7 get admin orders link in module

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I am building a module and I am trying to get the link directly or an order in the admin e.g. load up the order details page like adminXXXXXX/index.php/sell/orders/ORDERNUMBER.

I can get get a link to generate but it always sends me to the orders overview page (the list of orders) not directly into an order.

At the moment I am using:

```
$link = Context::getContext()->link;
$link = $link->getAdminLink('AdminOrders', true, [], ['id_customer' => 3473|intval, 'viewcustomer' => 1]);
$this->context->smarty->assign( "link", $link );
```

this generates:

```
/adminXXXXX/index.php/sell/orders/?id_customer=3473&viewcustomer=1&_token=XXXXXXXXXX
```

which just loads the view all orders page.

Can anyone shed any light how I link directly to the order details page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

worked it out. For anyone else it's:

```
$link->getAdminLink('AdminOrders', true, [], ['orderId' => ORDERNUMBER, 'vieworder' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Context::getContext()->link->getAdminLink(
            'AdminOrders',
            true,
            ['id_order' => (int) $transactions['id_order'], 'vieworder' => 1],
            ['id_order' => (int) $transactions['id_order'], 'vieworder' => 1]
        );
```

It is working for all PrestaShop versions